# Modal button: make the whole section clickable

Tags: css, wordpress, modal-dialog

I am currently working on this [website](http://www.aquila-pratteln.ch/startpage-two/) and as you can see I have 2 modals, one on the left and one on the right **(the i icons)**.

What I want to do is to keep the modal buttons in the same position but make the whole section (the pictures with the girl and the texts) clickable.

Infos: I can only use that "i" icon as modal button :/ and I can only edit the **CSS** not the HTML.

Is this possible to open the modal window by clicking on the whole section?

Here some code:

HTML:

```
<div id="ts-vcsc-modal-5397504-container" class="ts-vcsc-modal-container">
<div id="ts-vcsc-modal-5397504-trigger" style="" class="ts-vcsc-modal-5397504-parent nch-holder ts-vcsc-font-icon ts-font-icons ts-shortcode ts-icon-align-center    ">
<a href="#ts-vcsc-modal-5397504" class="nch-lightbox-modal no-ajaxy" data-width="1024" data-title="" data-open="false" data-delay="0" data-type="html" rel="" data-effect="slideUp" data-share="0" data-duration="5000" data-color="rgba(255,255,255,0.01)" data-lightbox-init="true">
<i class="ts-font-icon ts-awesome-info-circle" style="color: #ffffff; width:80px; height:80px; font-size:80px; line-height:80px;"></i></a></div>
<div id="ts-vcsc-modal-5397504" class="ts-modal-content nch-hide-if-javascript " style="display: none; padding: 15px; background: #0076bc;">
<div class="ts-modal-white-header"></div><div class="ts-modal-white-frame" style=""><div class="ts-modal-white-inner"><p></p>
<h2 style="text-align: left;"><span style="color: #ffffff;"><b>Wer seinen Mietvertrag im AQUILA bis 31.12.2016 unterzeichnet, erhält</b></span></h2>
<p><span style="color: #ffffff;">1 Nettomietzins geschenkt bei Einzug innert 3 Monaten</span><br>
<span style="color: #ffffff;"> 2 Nettomietzinse geschenkt bei Einzug per Dezember 2016</span></p>
<p><span style="color: #ffffff;">Zusätzlicher Weihnachtsgutschein von Sutter Begg oder AJ Salon hair &amp; make up im Wert von CHF 1000.–</span></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advice for your help.

Comment: What will happen after clicking on that whole section (the pictures with the girl and the texts) ?

Comment: @JimFahad open the modal window by clicking on the whole section

Comment: have you tried putting the whole section inside the anchor tag that triggers the modal?

Comment: I can't edit nothing in the HTML. Just via CSS or JS :/ @GvM

Comment: use jquery/javascript  click function

Answer (score 0):

```
.nch-lightbox-modal.no-ajaxy {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.ts-font-icon.ts-awesome-info-circle {
    color: #ffffff;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    font-size: 80px;
    line-height: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 25px;
    right: 0;
}
```

Try this to your anchor tag and icon

Comment: Thanks @GvM this works perfect on desktop. Is also possible to do the same on mobile?